# Use ethereumjs-wallet as a browser module

Tags: javascript, npm, ethereum, web3js

I have a need to create a wallet (generate account address and private key) in the browser without connecting to a node. If I understand correctly, in order to use web3.js we need to set a provider (Metamask or localnode) to use `web3.personal.newAccount("SEED", (response) => { console.log(response)})`

I found `ethereumjs-wallet` perfect for my use case but it exists only as a node module. Any way to use it as a browser module or alternatives to that?

Comment: I figured out a way to create browser builds of ethereumjs repos. Linked to the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/52867520/5378688

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another key management tool from [EthereumJS](https://github.com/ethereumjs/) community is the [Keythereum](https://github.com/ethereumjs/keythereum)

Keythereum is a JavaScript tool to generate, import and export Ethereum keys. This provides a simple way to use the same account locally and in web wallets. It can be used for verifiable cold storage wallets.

A minified, browserified file dist/keythereum.min.js is provided by them for use in the browser. Including this file simply attaches the keythereum object to window:

```
<script src="dist/keythereum.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

You can try with this one.

Comment: I tried your method as well and it worked but for the sake of simplicity I decided to go with the browser build process I linked in the comment of my question.